# link and join data in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am using smarty php template and sql server

I have the following tables :

```
table 1 (anime_pages) : contains data

table 2 (anime_genres) : contains categories

table 3 (genres_pages) : contains relationship between data and category
```

I am trying to show 3 random categories with 10 data results from that category.

I have the following php code right now :

```
$randomcsql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM anime_genres ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
while($ft5 = $db->fetch_array($randomcsql))
{
    $randomcats[] = $ft5; 
}
$smarty->assign('randomcats' , $randomcats);
$db->free_result($randomcsql);

$animecatssql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM anime_pages JOIN genres_pages ON anime_pages.id = genres_pages.genre_id  WHERE genres_pages.genre_id = (".$ft5['id'].") LIMIT 10 ");
while($ft6 = $db->fetch_array($animecatssql))
{
    $animecats[] = $ft6; 
}
$smarty->assign('animecats' , $animecats);
$db->free_result($animecatssql);
```

the problem is with (`".$ft5['id']."`) it is not giving me any result and If I replaced it with a number ... I will get a duplicated result (every data is duplicated twice)

How can I solve the problem ?

Is there a better code to use ?

I am trying to something like this : http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/5024/unled1qk.png

Comment: I am trying to something like this : http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/5024/unled1qk.png

Comment: Why don't you use the table names in the question as well as in the example code?  It makes it harder for us if we have to guess whether *table 1* is `anime_genres` or `genres_pages` or `anime_pages`, etc.  It also helps if you give us at least the most important columns in each of the tables (a relevant subset of the columns is fine).

Comment: Is `$ft5` going to be available outside of the `while` loop at all?

Comment: there is no ft5 outside the while loop

Comment: There isn't? Maybe look at your code again. http://codepad.org/m6T5L3WH

Comment: table 1 = anime_pages
table 2 = anime_genres 
table 3 = genres_pages

Comment: I do not know where to put the $ft5 outside the while loop .. I tried many places and non of them work

Comment: I believe that's because you can't. You have a loop, the `$ft5` is a *loop-scoped* variable. You have to save it to a variable outside of the scope for it to be available.

Comment: See: http://codepad.org/x7LbvZJ8

Comment: but ... if i put it there ... then it will give me different random results ??

Comment: Then I think your approach is flawed. `:)`

Comment: please see the image example so you can understand what I want to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4184/discussion-between-shnisaka-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: You probably want to do something like an `IN(ID1,ID2,ID3)` by `implode()`ing the random category ID's your previous queries returned. But this means you'll need to store them in an array in the first `while` loop. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by showing on random result instead of three

```
$randomcsql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM anime_genres ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
   while($ft5 = $db->fetch_array($randomcsql))
   {
   $randomcats[] = $ft5; 
   $animecatssql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM anime_pages JOIN genres_pages ON anime_pages.id = genres_pages.genre_id  WHERE genres_pages.genre_id = (".$ft5['id'].") LIMIT 10 ");
   while($ft6 = $db->fetch_array($animecatssql))
   {
   $animecats[] = $ft6; 
   }
   }
   $smarty->assign('randomcats' , $randomcats);
   $db->free_result($randomcsql);
   $smarty->assign('animecats' , $animecats);
   $db->free_result($animecatssql);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
$animecatssql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM anime_pages JOIN genres_pages ON anime_pages.id = (".$ft5['id'].") LIMIT 10 ");
```

you are using `$ft5` variable which dont exists here as its outside your while condition of fethcing data.

and you also said that you want 3 random categories and 10 data sets from them. so you basically want 30 data sets in total (10 for each). you should be using this query inside a loop which will run three times for the array `$randomcats`. and also your this array will be having arrays as values for each three keys. so you have to go to the values of the array (which will be a array again) and then on there value you can get your value you are searching for.

Hope i am clear. if not please mention.